# Entropy variation of thermostat

Tags: thermodynamics

My question is the following. I consider a system S in contact with a thermostat, the system receives a heat $Q$ from it.

What we can write is:

$$\Delta S_S \geq \frac{Q}{T}$$

This is exactly the second principle.

However, for the thermostat, I have often read that $\Delta S_{T} = -\frac{Q}{T}$

Why are we sure to have an **equality** in the case of the thermostat ?

Comment: Where have you read that and in what context?

Comment: By a thermostat, do you mean an ideal reservoir?

Comment: @BobD I have to refind the source but I found this in various lectures. By a thermostat I mean an ideal reservoir of temperature $T$.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal constant temperature reservoir is defined as an entity with a very high thermal conductivity and heat capacity, such that its temperature is everywhere uniform and never changes significantly.  In this limit, its entropy change is always $Q_R/T$, where $Q_R$ is minus Q for the system.

In all cases, if you are working with a surroundings consisting of a constant temperature reservoir, all the entropy generation for an irreversible process is assumed to occur within the system, and none of the entropy generation is assumed to occur within the reservoir.  So the overall entropy change for the combination of system and surroundings in an irreversible process is given by $$\Delta S=\Delta S_{system}-\frac{Q}{T}>0$$with $$\Delta S_{system}>\frac{Q}{T}$$

ADDENDUM

For a finite reservoir of mass M, specific heat capacity C, initial temperature T, heat received from the system $Q_R$, and corresponding temperature rise $\Delta T$, the change in entropy of the reservoir would be $$\Delta S=MC\ln{\left[\frac{T+\Delta T}{T}\right]}=MC\ln{\left[1+\frac{\Delta T}{T}\right]}$$Since $Q_R=MC\Delta T$, we then have$$\Delta S=MC\ln{\left[1+\frac{Q_R}{MCT}\right]}$$In the limit of $MC\rightarrow\infty$, this approaches $$\Delta S=\frac{Q_R}{T}$$So, for an ideal constant temperature reservoir, this will always be the entropy change, irrespective of the process irreversibility within the system.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. This is the kind of answer I am looking for, however I would appreciate if you can elaborate a little bit. For instance why "in this limit, its entropy change is always QR/T". Could you provide a calculation to help me to understand this statement ? Also, why is the following true "In all cases, if you are working with a surroundings consisting of a constant temperature reservoir, all the entropy generation for an irreversible process is assumed to occur within the system, and none of the entropy generation is assumed to occur within the reservoir." ? Thanks!

Comment: See the ADDENDUM